# How do I resove the ImportError encountered while using the fssa package in python?

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am using python from a anaconda installation and using the python
notebook. From the jupyer notebook (ipython) I import fssa like:

```
 import fssa
```

I get the following error message (see below).

Any help from you will be appreciated.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling scipy, numpy, and fssa and reinstalling
them, but the problem seems to remain.

```
 ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_218856/781571052.py in <module>
----> 1 import fssa

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fssa/__init__.py in <module>
     82
     83 import pkg_resources
---> 84 from .fssa import scaledata, quality, autoscale
     85
     86 __version__ = pkg_resources.get_distribution(__name__).version

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fssa/fssa.py in <module>
     46 import scipy.optimize
     47
---> 48 from .optimize import _minimize_neldermead
     49
     50

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fssa/optimize.py in <module>
     11 import numpy
     12 from numpy import asfarray
---> 13 from scipy.optimize.optimize import (OptimizeResult,
     14                                      _status_message, wrap_function)
     15

ImportError: cannot import name 'wrap_function' from 'scipy.optimize.optimize'
(/home/debasish/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/optimize/optimize.py)
```